# RUBY - How to call a method from another class

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm new to ruby and programming in general and I'm having some issues getting methods to work from another class. The method I'm trying to get to work is new_employee and its option 2 if you run the business.rb 
business.rb file contains class Business

```
  class Business
  attr_accessor :name

  def run
    self.welcome
  end 

  def welcome
     while true
       puts "Welcome to Team Green Turf! What do you want to do today?"
       puts "1. Add new customer"
       puts "2. Add new employee"
       puts "3. View current revenue"
       choice = gets.chomp.to_i

      case choice 
         when 1
           puts "hello!"
         when 2
           puts new_employee()
         when 3
           exit

      end 
     end
  end 
end

team_green_turf = Business.new
team_green_turf.run
```

## ---------------------------------

employees.rb file

```
require_relative 'business'

class Employees

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end 

  def new_employee(name)
    puts "What is the employees name?"
    name = gets.chomp
    e1 = Employees.new(name)
  end 


end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ideas:

1. You need to ensure that the Ruby interpreter has loaded the file containing the method before you attempt to call it.  In your case, you are executing the code at the botton of `business.rb` before the `employees.rb` file has been fully loaded, so the `Employee` class and its methods will not be defined.  You could fix this in many different ways, but I suggest moving the last two lines of `business.rb` into their own file called `run.rb` and putting `require_relative 'business'` at the top of `run.rb`, and putting `require_relative 'employees'` at the top of `business.rb`, and removing the `require_relative 'business'` from the top of `employees.rb`.  (The `Employees` class does not actually use or depend on the `Business` class so it doesn't make sense to require it.)
2. You need to provide the proper prefixes to the method to get it to be called.  In your case, you want to call the function from the `Business` class, you would write `Employees.new_employee`.  You would also need to change `new_employee` to be a class method by putting `self.` before its name when you are defining it:  `def self.new_employee(name)...`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work! So to make a class method always put self.methodname ?? That would make sense why none of my methods have been working.

Comment: Yep, that's how you make a class method.